# getting 404 error when install react with npm create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

i want to install react app with this

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

but i got this error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://repo.huaweicloud.com/repository/npm/jsx-ast-utils/-/jsx-ast-utils-3.3.5.tgz
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'jsx-ast-utils@https://repo.huaweicloud.com/repository/npm/jsx-ast-utils/-/jsx-ast-utils-3.3.5.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\henry\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-10T06_18_22_392Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\xampp\htdocs\Practice
Done.
```

My node version is v18.12.1 and npm version is 8.19.2

Comment: Whats the output of `npm config get registry`? Looks like you are using a different npm registry which doesnt have this package version.

Comment: https://repo.huaweicloud.com/repository/npm/

the output is this link

Comment: I think `create-react-app` is no longer maintained. See recommended https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this package is not available in huaweicloud registry, you can install it from the main npmjs registry using:

```
npm install jsx-ast-utils --reg https://registry.npmjs.com
```

---

You can also set the NPM registry to use for the whole project, by creating a `.npmrc` at the root of your project, with the contents:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.com

// if you are using scoped packages for your company,
@yourcompany:registry=https://repo.huaweicloud.com
```